# How can I hide depots from my view in p4v?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm an admin for the system, so I can see all depots in our p4 server. However, I only actually care about a handful of them.

How can I filter which depots are displayed based on which workspace I have selected? I've tried editing the workspace, context-clicking the depot, and selecting `exclude tree`, but this doesn't work. In my mappings, I can see the only depots I want to view.. however, I still see all available depots in the workspace `Depot` tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem might be your settings. Go to *Search-->Filter Depot* and select *Tree Restricted to Workspace View*

Answer (score 3):

First answer should do the trick. There is another way to get to that option quicker using the filter in the main view

[image: p4v restrict to workspace]